# What if I change a Dockerfile while a build is running out of it?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-registry

If an image is currently being built out of a Dockerfile and I perform some changes on that Dockerfile itself, will it affect subsequent steps of the build?

Comment: i dont think so, the Dockerfile is read completly at the start of the build process.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not until you re-run it.  The first version of the Dockerfile would be in memory and have no awareness of your changes.

Answer (score 0):

You should see the *Dockerfile* as the source code of your container (like C, C++ or Go) and see the docker image as a compiled binary, actually the docker image is just a binary file, so the *Dockerfile* matters only when you do a `docker build -t containerName .` command, after all the container is just a file that you can run or move to anywhere where you can do a `docker run containerName`.

So short answer it doesn't matter at all :)